# TSQL date strangeness - two servers, same collation, different date interpretations

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-collation

We develop an industry niche software that works with SQL Server. We have a customer that upgraded their SQL Server from Version 12 to Version 15 (SQL2014 to SQL2019) and ever since then, we've had date troubles.

At first, we thought it was the Server Collation, as it was different to our specifications (someone was apparently sleeping during the upgrade). So, we installed a test server, standard install in pretty much every aspect (and we set the Collation [Latin1_General_CI_AS] correctly). Now the server at our Customer is pretty much a twin of the one we use internally - and the problem persists.

The following is a test script:

```
declare @x1 as datetime
set @x1 = '20231231'
--set @x1 = '2023-12-31'
--set @x1 = '12.31.2023'

select @x1
```

Notice @x1 - The first format works for both servers. The second and the third only works on the customers server. Also, the first two formats happen to coincide with ISO-8601 - which is double strange that the first two don't work on both servers.

Now, to expand this example:

```
DECLARE @T1 AS DATE
DECLARE @T2 AS DATE
DECLARE @T3 AS DATE
DECLARE @T4 AS DATE

DECLARE @nT1 AS VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @nT2 AS VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @nT3 AS VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @nT4 AS VARCHAR(10)

set @nT1 = '2023-10-24'
set @nT2 = '20231024'
set @nT3 = '24.10.2023'
set @nT4 = '2023.10.24'

set @T1 = cast(@nT1 as date)
set @T2 = cast(@nT2 as date)
set @T3 = cast(@nT3 as date)
set @T4 = cast(@nT4 as date)

select @t1, @t2, @t3, @t4, @nt1, @nt2, @nt3, @nt4
```

The script goes through without a problem on our end. Not, however, on the customers end. The customers server is unable to cast @T3.

So ... what is going on here?
The servers are pretty much identical - we explicitly installed a new test server specifically for this, and yet; no dice.

Also, I realise that using VARCHAR and DATES in the same line are a mortal sin - but thats just how our procedure parameters are defined and the boss wants to keep it that way.

Comment: Dates are date. strings dates are just a representation. Pass params as dates. It's the only sane way. What locale does the customer have set? You should be specifying an explicit (hopefully ISO8601) format and not allowing CAST to decide how a date should look.

Comment: Stick to `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn` for string literal dates; those are the only 2 safe formats across data types and language settings.

Comment: Your boss is mistaken, be careful what you learn from your boss

Comment: You should check what results you get with running `DBCC useroptions`. Collation does not equal language settings, just defines how strings are handled for stuff like sorting. Also you're both checking with datetime and date variables. These use different date ranges and have different associated iso norms, datetime2 would be more equivalent to it's working as a 'timeless' date component. Datetime is not considered ANSI or ISO 8601 compliant. If you must keep the source as string, you should use a CONVERT() statement and explicitly specify the formatting.

Comment: @DKramer yes, DBCC useroptions does give me different values. Ill change these and give feedback.

Yes, in my longer script, I do have converts (date, @t, 104/20), they dont change the script error behavior so I omitted them in the post

Comment: Why are you, seemingly, so against using an unambiguous string literal value?

Comment: The setting you're looking for is `set dateformat 'dmy'`vs `set dateformat 'ymd'` . as other's said though, using ambigious format is a fools errand

Comment: @DKramer By golly you're right ... it works now. The weird thing about this is how the US language options apparently do not respect the ISO 8601 ... but huge thanks!

Comment: although, let me qualify this - @Thom A,@siggemannen, yes, if due dilligence was done in creating the procedure and the parameters being passed to the procedure, this would not be an issue - alas, I was but a wee lad of 8 when this script came into being so ....

Comment: Age when it came out is irrelevant, @TheKDude . You are in a position *now* to fix the problem at the root cause; the use of ambiguous date formats.

Comment: I know what you mean, the problem lies in the historical details and ... people involved, lets say, as well as the complexity of the system. We are, however, planning to overhaul this aspect of our software so a much better solution is in the works

Answer (score 0):

Here a more detailed description:

MSSQL MS does locale-settings (LS) per user (login, more specifically). This includes the SQL-Commands coming from that session. We were getting errors in converting datetime formats because the LS of the SQL-login session were set to a different cultural setting than what our scripts were designed for.

The solution was to dictate the LS of the executing user in question (finding it out with [DBCC USEROPTIONS;] and then going from there either creating an explicit login with manual LS settings, setting up group policy, etc).

The LS, if not using a specific SQL-Login and not dictated by group policy, is pulled from the OS that is opening a session.

Nice to know though:
When programming in C#, there is a ToShortDateString() extension (for example) that, depending on the Culture settings of the thread, formats the date in its cultural context.
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring?view=net-7.0].

This, coupled with how MSSQL MS handles cultural settings, is actually pretty rad.